# Foreach loop in PHP and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I want is to add category to class only in category page in woocommerce.So for that I am doing like this :

```
$categories = array('menu','hot-drinks', 'salads', 'sandwiches', 'pastries', 'breakfast', 'sauces', 'cold-drinks', 'breads', 'aroma-signatures', 'soups');

foreach($categories as $cat){

    if($_GET['product_cat'] == $cat){  ?>

<div class="left-block">

    <div class="left-navigation-container <?php echo $cat; ?>" > 

<?php }
} ?>
```

What I want is when there is no product_cat in the URL it should use

```
<div class="left-block">

    <div class="left-navigation-container">
```

But as I used foreach loop, I can't put it else there and I also can't put it outside the loop.

What Should I do ?Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your HTML code is incorrect. `<div>Visible contents</div>`. You have not closed even one `<div>` tag with `</div>`. This currently nests all divs in one another. They are without visible content as well.

Comment: *But as I used foreach loop, I can't put it else there and I also can't put it outside the loop.* what do you mean? Plus, this should belong to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com or WooCommerce support site itself.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with both WP and WooCommerce

Comment: @Raptor We can't ask coding related question on wordpress SO

Comment: @Rolice Its WP so closing tag is in other file.

Comment: I am sorry but what is the problem! Your `if` statement is in the `foreach` loop, so why cant your `else` or `else if` statement not be in the loop?  your first closing bracket is the `if` statement, not the `foreach` statement

Comment: For each iteration it will generate left-block nested content. So any content below will be nested in variable node nest which might lead to unexpected behaviour. `left-block->left-nav-left-block`...
It will be a single cat, but this code is a potential spawner of unexpected behavior.

Comment: The reason is that it will consider `<div>` each and every time.So my output will become something like this :
`<div class="left-block">
    <div class="left-navigation-container"> 
 <div class="left-block">
    <div class="left-navigation-container"> ` and so on for 8 times ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is when there is no product_cat in the URL it should use

Just turn your words into a basic `if` condition, like:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['product_cat']): ?>

<?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>

    if ($_GET['product_cat'] == $cat): ?>

    <div class="left-block">
      <div class="left-navigation-container <?php echo $cat; ?>" > 

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else: ?>

<div class="left-block">

    <div class="left-navigation-container">   

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And yet, the `foreach` will output nested divs.

Comment: What do you mean? There's the condition `if ($_GET['product_cat'] == $cat)` which ensures that output will be done in case it meets that condition (i.e only once, since arrays can't contain the same key)

Comment: It is giving me the syntax error on this line `<?php if (isset($_GET['product_cat']): ?>` that **unexpected ':'**

Comment: @Twix oh yeah sorry I forgot one closing bracket `product_cat']))` <- add one more bracket

Comment: Ok ..It worked for me ..Just want to ask Is it good practice to do coding like this ?
Accepted and +1 :)

Comment: @Twix Yes, First of all, it's better to use alternate (as you can see in the answer) syntax for templates, rather than `<?php if (...) { some html <?php } ?>` And second, the term *coding style* applies more for programming languages, like JS and PHP, rather than your presentation. Anyway, if you feel that it's easy to read and maintain your thing, then your style must be ok.